# How to change value of variable when found user with same name in Database?

Tags: java, sql

I want to change value of `doesThatUsernameExist` to true if in my database, user with same username exist.
I don't know how to make it by SQL code.

That's how I wanted to method looks like:

```
public boolean doesAccountWithThatUsernameExist(User user) throws SQLException {
    boolean doesThatUsernameExist = false;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT username FROM user WHERE username=?"); // < that's wrong
    preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getName());
    ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();

    ....
    return doesThatUsernameExist;
}
```

Comment: Your SQL looks like it should work like that. The thing is, you execute your query but you don't check and interpret the results. Do you get an error of some sort or do you just don't know how to browse results?

Comment: I didn't know how to browse result. Hopefully, @guleryuz helped. :)

Comment: Great. If your usernames are not case sensitive, I suggest you  `UPPER(` them for the comparison in the SQL.

Comment: @Dessma well that's fact, but if name in database is for example: "Admin" and if I make `.user.getName().toUpperCase()` then ADMIN!=Admin.

Comment: That's why I said "them" :) as in uppercase both hands of the `=`, so `UPPER(username)=?`

Comment: nah, it's not necessery. I see that no matter what, "admin", "Admin","ADmin", everything is equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`resultset.next()` returns `true` if there is a matching record, `false` otherwise. so you can use its result:

```
public boolean doesAccountWithThatUsernameExist(User user) throws SQLException {
    boolean doesThatUsernameExist = false;
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connection.prepareStatement("SELECT username FROM user WHERE username=?"); // < that's wrong
    preparedStatement.setString(1, user.getName());
    ResultSet result = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
    doesThatUsernameExist = result.next();
    return doesThatUsernameExist;
}
```